# How to install leanpkg with elan and Lean 4

Tags: lean

How do I install `leanpkg` for Lean 4?

I installed [elan](https://github.com/leanprover/elan) and then installed the latest milestone and nightly releases of Lean 4:

```
$ elan install v4.0.0-m5
$ elan install nightly
```

There are many online resources that suggest using `leanpkg` as a package manager for Lean 4 libraries, but running it throws an elan error:

```
$ leanpkg
error: toolchain 'nightly' does not have the binary `.../.elan/toolchains/nightly/bin/leanpkg`
```

Indeed, the distribution didn't seem to have come with a `leanpkg` binary:

```
$ ls ~/.elan/toolchains/v4.0.0-m5/bin/
clang  lake  ld.lld  lean  leanc  leanmake  llvm-ar
$ ls ~/.elan/toolchains/nightly/bin/
clang  lake  ld.lld  lean  leanc  leanmake  llvm-ar
```

Comment: _"There are many online resources that suggest using leanpkg as a package manager for Lean 4 libraries"_ [citation needed]. Are you sure these resources weren't talking about Lean 3? Can you edit your question to link to them?

Answer (score 2):

`leanpkg` has been replaced with [Lake](https://github.com/leanprover/lake) in Lean 4.

(Thanks to Mauricio Collares for pointing this out to me!)